# Importing Wikipedia to local Media Wiki creates pages full of templates references

Tags: mysql, mediawiki, wikipedia

I downloaded a wikipedia XML dump and imported it into a local Media Wiki installation. For that purpose, I used `mwdumper` to generate a SQL script. The exact command I executed was:

```
java -jar mwdumper.jar --format=mysql:1.5 --filter=notalk --filter=namespace:\!NS_USER --filter=latest enwiki-20160601-pages-articles-multistream.xml > enwiki-20160601-pages-articles-multistream.sql
```

For it to work with my local media wiki database, I first had to add a `page_counter` column to the `page` table. Then, I executed the script (and it took hours and hours to complete).

Now it has finished, but when I access the generated, I find a lot of references to templates. For example, this is the first paragraph of the Foobar article:

```
{{#invoke:Distinguish|distinguish}} {{#invoke:redirect hatnote|redirect|1}} The terms foobar (Template:IPAc-en), or foo and others are used as placeholder names (also referred to as metasyntactic variables) in computer programming or computer-related documentation.<ref name="rfc3092">{{#invoke:citation/CS1|citation |CitationClass=web }}</ref> They have been used to name entities such as variables, functions, and commands whose exact identity is unimportant and serve only to demonstrate a concept.
```

How can I fix this? Do I have to install some kind of extensions my Media Wiki or what? Is there a better way to obtain a local instance of Wikipedia?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I get templates for MediaWiki?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678626/where-can-i-get-templates-for-mediawiki)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're missing the [Scribunto extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto). You'll want to ensure you have copied the correct Module: namespace pages too, e.g. `Module:Distinguish` for `#invoke:Distinguish`.